# Next js taking props from a specific item of a Json

Tags: reactjs, json, next.js

I have a list of products in a json with their props, and I want to take that props of that specific item by his ID to a different file. How can I do that if the route isn't dynamic? (Normally i would take the router.query.id).

This is the json example:

```
export const ArtroscopiaPlus = [

{
    title: 'product 1',
    url: 'https://drive.example1',
    id: 'grapa-iql',
    img: '/img/productos/Artroscopia/img1.jpg'
},

{
    title: 'Product 2',
    url: 'https://drive.example2',
    id: 'kurosaca-romo',
    img: '/img/productos/Artroscopia/img3.jpg'
},
{
    title: 'Product 3',
    url: 'https://drive.example3',
    id: 'tornillo-transversal',
    img: '/img/productos/Artroscopia/img4.jpg'
},
```

And this is the code where I can inject that props:

```
const GrapaIQL = () => {

return (
    <>
        <ItemS>
            <TitleItem className="title-item">{Prop with the title}</TitleItem>
            <ContentItem>
                <ImageDiv className="image-div">
                    <ItemImg src="{prop with the img}" alt={`${titulo} Company`} className="item-img" data-aos="fade-right" />
                </ImageDiv>
                <div className="info-div">
                    <table class="tabla-chica" data-aos="fade-left">
                        
                        (not relevant table content)

                    </table>
                </div>
                <Pdf path='{Prop with the path}' />
            </ContentItem>

            <ScrollArrow />
        </ItemS>
```

Comment: also share the parent component of `GrapaIQL` (where do you use it).

Comment: GrapaIQL is in the page folder, it's a page, not a reusable component

Comment: So, where or when you can determine the proper item from `ArtroscopiaPlus` ?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to access the item with ID `grapa-iql` from the `ArtroscopiaPlus` array inside the `GrapaIQL` page? If so, then why not hardcode the ID on the page and access the item?